# Passing parameter through "window.location.href"

Tags: php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Post Answer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    include ("connection.php");

      $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE SID='$_POST[sid]'") or die('Query failed');
      $tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      $nn = $tmp['nickname'];
      $a = $_POST['answer'];
      $sid = $tmp['SID'];
      $c = $tmp['course'];
      $q_id = $_POST['q_id'];
      $sql = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "project");
      $sql = "INSERT INTO answer_table (nickname, answer, SID, vote, course) VALUES ('$nn', '$a', '$sid', '', '$c')";

      if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }

      echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.location.href='question.php';
                window.alert('Thank You! Your answer is online now.')
                  </SCRIPT>");
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

At `question.php` file, I want to receive `$q_id` as `$_GET['q_id']`

Can I pass `$q_id` of line 17 to `question.php` page of line 26?

Comment: **`question.php?q_id=7`** ?

Comment: "=7" i don't understand that... @Darren

Comment: Look at Seths answer.

Comment: Yes, why not? Have you tried it, is anything not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it in as a query string in the javascript

```
echo ("<script language='JavaScript'>
         window.location.href='question.php?q_id=$q_id';
         window.alert('Thank You! Your answer is online now.')
       </script>");
```

Answer (score -2):

Though it's 4 years too late, but @Seth's answer is probably not correct. Placing a PHP variable inside a Javascript won't work, it must be echoed.

```
echo ("<script language='JavaScript'>
     window.location.href='question.php?q_id=<?php echo $q_id ?>';
     window.alert('Thank You! Your answer is online now.')
   </script>");
```

"< ?php echo $q_id ?>" will pass the value contained in $q_id to the JS function.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The variable is evaluated OK when placed within doublequotes (`"`) nested under PHP statement (the `echo` here). The fact that the surrounding script is actually javascript code doesn't matter at all. See it running [here](https://3v4l.org/FblZQ)

Comment: Have you tried to run the code provided by Seth? What makes you think that it should not work? Using your code, the redirect would happen using `q_id=<?php echo $q_id ?>` (while `$q_id` would be replaced with the actual ID), which does not look like the expected output

Comment: I faced a similar (not exactly same) situation in my project & while searching I came to this post. I tried the code provided by Seth which didn't workout. echoing the PHP variable sorted my issue. May be I interpreted the original question wrongly, but ultimately the information in this thread solved my problem.