# Unable to redirect from index.php to home.php

Tags: php, header

```
{
      ?>
      <?php
      $sql1 = mysqli_query($sql1,"select * from register where email='$name' AND password='$pass'");
      $r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
      $id = $r['id'];
      echo $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
      ?>
      <script>
        **window.location = 'Home.php?id=<?php echo $id?>';**
      </script>
      <?php
  }
?>
```

I am using window.location instead of header to redirect to the next page with session id in the URL.

This leads me to this:

> This page isn’t working
>
> localhost redirected you too many times.
>
> Try clearing your cookies.
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Check out the index file:

Index.php

```
<?php
require("user_agent.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>:: Online Bus-Ticket Reservation ::</title>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />-->
<style>
.table tr td {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-right-style: outset
    border-right-color: darkred;
    border-bottom-color: darkred;
}

.table {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: outset;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left-color: darkred;
    border-top-color: darkred;
    font-size: 16px;
}
a{
    background-color:#3366FF;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    border:groove;
    font-weight:550;
}
</style>


<script language="javascript"> 


    function validate()  {
        if(document.getElementById('user').value==''){
            alert('Please enter Username!');
            document.getElementById('username').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(document.getElementById('pass').value==''){
            alert('Please enter Password!');
            document.getElementById('pwd').focus();
            return false;
        }

     return true;
    }
</script>

</head>

<body topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" bgcolor="#CCFF99">
<div align="center" style="width:807">

<embed src="banner3.swf" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="807" height="150" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" allowScriptAccess="always"></embed>

</div>
<table bgcolor="#FFCCFF" style="margin-top:0" align="center" width="800px" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td height="5px" align="center" bgcolor="#330000" colspan="2">
<h2 style="text-align:center; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; margin-top:3px">

Welcome To Online Bus-Ticket Reservation</h2></td></tr>

<tr><td bgcolor="#CC6600" align="center" style="color:#FFFFCC; font-size:14px; display:table" id="clock" colspan="2">



        <script type="text/javascript">
            var lastText = "";

            function updateClock() {
                var d = new Date();
                var s = "";
                s += (10 > d.getHours()   ? "0" : "") + d.getHours()   + ":"
                s += (10 > d.getMinutes() ? "0" : "") + d.getMinutes() + ":"
                s += (10 > d.getSeconds() ? "0" : "") + d.getSeconds();

                if (lastText != s) {
                    setText("clock", s);
                    lastText = s;
                }

            }

            function setText(elemName, text) {
                var elem = document.getElementById(elemName);
                while (elem.childNodes.length > 0)
                    elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
                elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            }

            updateClock();
            setInterval(updateClock,100);
        </script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 var d=new Date();
var monthname=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"); 

var TODAY =d.getDate() +"- " + monthname[d.getMonth()] + "-" + d.getFullYear();

 document.write(TODAY);
</script>



</tr>

<tr><td height="153" colspan="2">

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="800" height="150">
  <param name="movie" value="project.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <embed src="project.swf"
         quality="high"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         width="800"
         height="150"
         allowFullScreen="false"
         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
         allowScriptAccess="always" />
</object>


  </td></tr>

<tr><td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" bordercolordark="#FFFFFF" align="left" colspan="2">
<h3 style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #000; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px">Login Screen</h3></td></tr>

<tr><td width="398">

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="f">


<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Email: <input style="size:auto; width:150px" id="user" type="text" name="user" value="" />
</p>
<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" align="center">Password:  
  <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" style="size:auto; width:150px" />
</p>
<center>
<input type="submit" onclick="validate()" value="Login" name="s" style="background-color:maroon; height:20px; color:#FFF; font-weight:50" /> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="bus_rev.php" style="cursor:default; font-size:12px; background-color:#900;">New User</a></center>
</form>
<?php
session_start();
require("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['s'])){
$name = $_POST['user']; 
$pass = $_POST['pass']; 

  $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from register where email='$name' AND password='$pass'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==0)
  {
      ?>
      <script>
      alert("You seem to registered before!!!");
      </script>
      <?php
  }
  else
  {
      ?>
      <?php
      $sql1 = mysqli_query($sql1,"select * from register where email='$name' AND password='$pass'");
      $r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
      $id = $r['id'];
      echo $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
      ?>
      <script>
        window.location.href='Home.php?id=$id';
      </script>
      <?php
  }
}

?>

</td><td width="400">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="400" height="166">
  <param name="movie" value="project1.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <embed src="project1.swf"
         quality="high"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         width="400"
         height="166"
         allowFullScreen="false"
         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
         allowScriptAccess="always" />
</object></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div align="center"><img align="top" width="806" src="images1/footer.jpg" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>:: HOME ::</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\NARPAT\Desktop\basiccalendar.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/table.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
<style>
a{cursor:default;}
</style>

</head>

<body topmargin="0" bottommargin="0">



<div align="center">
<embed src="banner3.swf" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="807" height="150" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" allowScriptAccess="always"></embed>
</div>
<table bgcolor="#FFFFCC" style="margin-top:0" align="center" width="807" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

<tr><td colspan="3" bgcolor="#330000" align="center" height="5px">
<h1 style="text-align:center; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:22px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; margin-top:3px">

Welcome To Online Bus-Ticket Reservation</h1></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="3" bgcolor="#CC6600" align="center" style="color:#FFFFCC; font-size:14px">
|| <b><?php echo date("D d-M-Y");?></b> ||</td></tr>                                        

<!-- end header -->
<?php
require("config.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
$uid = $_SESSION['id']; 
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from register where id = '$uid'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0)
{
    $r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    $name = $r['name'];     
}
 ?>



 </td></tr>   <tr><td width="200">
<!-- start leftmenu -->
<dl id="browse"> 
    <!-- <dt>
        <a href=""></a>
    </dt> -->
        &nbsp;<span class="simpletext1">Welcome :<b><?php echo $name;?></b></span>

        <hr />                  

  <dd   style="text-align: left">  
        <img align="absmiddle" src="images/home.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /><a href="Home.php?id=<?php echo $uid;?>">Home</a>
    </dd>
  <dd style="text-align: left">
        <img align="absmiddle" src="images/password.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /><a href="password_update.php?id=<?php echo $uid;?>">Change Password</a>
    </dd>
  <dd style="text-align: left">
        <img align="absmiddle" src="images/profile.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $uid;?>">View Profile</a>
    </dd>

  <dd style="text-align: left">
        <img align="absmiddle" src="images/ticket.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /><a href="myticket.php?id=<?php echo $uid;?>">My Tickets</a>
    </dd>

   <dd style="text-align: left">
        <img align="absmiddle" src="images/logout.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </dd>
</dl>
<!-- end leftmenu --></td><td width="380">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="382" height="195">
  <param name="movie" value="rstc.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
  <embed src="rstc.swf"
         quality="high"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         WMODE="transparent"
         width="382"
         height="195"
         allowFullScreen="true"
         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
         allowScriptAccess="always" />
</object>


</td>
<td width="217">
<embed src="rightbar.swf" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="217" height="195" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" allowScriptAccess="always"></embed>

</tr></table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="maintable" align="center"
               width="805" valign="middle">
<form method="post">
    <tr class="tabtitle">
            <td colspan="4">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="800">
                    <tr>  
                        <td  class="titletext" style="background-color:#990000">
                            <font size="3px" style="background-color:#C00; color:#FFF">Search For Bus Services </font>


                        </td>


                  </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%" class="simpletext">
                From Stop :
            </td>
            <td>
            <select class="html-text-box" style="background-color:; font-style:oblique; width:100px; font-family:Verdana; font-weight:bold" name="from">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">-Select-</option>
            <option value="BARMER">BARMER</option>
            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
            <option value="Jaipur">Jaipur</option>
            <option value="JODHPUR">JODHPUR</option></select>
          </td>
                        <td width="23%"  class="simpletext" align="right">
                To Stop :
            </td>
            <td  align="left">
            <select class="html-text-box" style="font-style:oblique; width:100px; font-family:Verdana; font-weight:bold" name="to">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">-Select-</option>
            <option value="BARMER" >BARMER</option>
            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
            <option value="Jaipur">Jaipur</option>
            <option value="JODHPUR">JODHPUR</option></select>
            </td>
        </tr>

                <tr>
            <td >
                Journey Date :
            </td>
            <td  >
                <input type="text" style="border:2; padding:2" name="journeyDate" maxlength="10" size="10" value="" id="journeyDate">

            </td>


        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" height="45" align="center" valign="middle">
                            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" onclick="return callfrm(document.getElementById('currentdate').value);" class="html-button">

                       <input type="submit" name="resert" value="Reset"  class="html-button">

                        </td>
                </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <div class="errormessage" align="center">

                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>  
    </form>
    </table>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    require('config.php');
     $from = $_POST['from'];
     $to = $_POST['to'];

     $query = mysqli_query("select * from bus where from_stop ='$from' AND to_stop ='$to'");
     $c = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query);
    if($c>0)
    {
?>
<table width="805" height="62" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="table" bordercolor="#000000" b>

<tr align="center"><td width="115">Bus Name</td><td width="122">From</td><td width="117">To</td><td width="117">Dept Time</td><td width="119">Arrival Time</td><td width="110">Distance</td><td width="110">Fare</td><td>Available</td><td width="101">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<?php
while($r1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $bus= $r1['id'];
    $bus_name = $r1['bus_name'];
    $from = $r1['from_stop'];
    $to = $r1['to_stop'];
    $dept_time = $r1['dept_time'];
    $arrival_time = $r1['arrival_time'];
    $distance = $r1['distance'];
    $fare = $r1['fare'];

    $bust = $bus.'bus';
    $query1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * from $bust where status='Available'");
    $c = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
?>

<tr align="center"><td><?php echo $bus_name;?></td><td><?php echo $from;?></td><td><?php echo $to;?></td><td><?php echo $dept_time;?></td><td><?php echo $arrival_time;?></td><td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $distance;?></td><td><?php echo $fare; ?></td><td><?php echo $c;?></td><td><a href="res.php?id=<?php echo $uid;?>&bus=<?php echo $bus;?>">Book</a>
</td></tr></table>
<?php
}
}
}
?>


     <table class="table" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="805">
     <tr><td height="124"><marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" draggable="auto" bgcolor="#663333" loop="-1" dropzone="move" direction="left" behavior="alternate" scrollamount="2" scrolldelay="1">
     <img border="1" height="130" width="150" src="images/B1.jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/B2.jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/B3.jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/B4.jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/B5.jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/B6.jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/7.png" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/v (1).jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/v (2).jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/v (3).jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/v (4).jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/v (5).jpg" />
     <img height="130" width="150" src="images/v (6).jpg" />
     <img border="1" height="130" width="150" src="images/v (7).jpg" />

     </marquee></td>
     <div style="position:absolute; float:right; visibility:hidden">
     <script type="text/javascript">

var todaydate=new Date()
var curmonth=todaydate.getMonth()+1 //get current month (1-12)
var curyear=todaydate.getFullYear() //get current year

document.write(buildCal(curmonth ,curyear, "main", "month", "daysofweek", "days", 1));
</script>



<form>
<select onChange="updatecalendar(this.options)">
<script type="text/javascript">

var themonths=['January','February','March','April','May','June',
'July','August','September','October','November','December']

var todaydate=new Date()
var curmonth=todaydate.getMonth()+1 //get current month (1-12)
var curyear=todaydate.getFullYear() //get current year

function updatecalendar(theselection){
var themonth=parseInt(theselection[theselection.selectedIndex].value)+1
var calendarstr=buildCal(themonth, curyear, "main", "month", "daysofweek", "days", 0)
if (document.getElementById)
document.getElementById("calendarspace").innerHTML=calendarstr
}

document.write('<option value="'+(curmonth-1)+'" selected="yes">Current Month</option>')
for (i=0; i<12; i++) //display option for 12 months of the year
document.write('<option value="'+i+'">'+themonths[i]+' '+curyear+'</option>')


</script>
</select>

<div id="calendarspace">
<script>
//write out current month's calendar to start
document.write(buildCal(curmonth, curyear, "main", "month", "daysofweek", "days", 0))
</script>
</div>

</form>



<script type="text/javascript">

var todaydate=new Date()
var curmonth=todaydate.getMonth()+1 //get current month (1-12)
var curyear=todaydate.getFullYear() //get current year

</script>

     </div>
     </tr>

</table>                                      
<div align="center"><img align="top" width="805" src="images1/footer.jpg" />
</div>
<?php
}
else
{
    header("Location:indexm.php");
}
}
else
{
    header("Location:Home.php?id=$uid");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.php is uses sql function from config.php file to get database connectivity.

Comment: remove `echo` from `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;` and check

Comment: Thanks, but its not working....
I m getting blank in id in URL
"http://localhost/abc/Home.php?id="

Comment: @AlivetoDie Check this...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072570/passing-parameter-through-window-location-href

Comment: I have said from other line and you remove from other line. Please read my comment carefully. remove `echo` from line  `echo $_SESSION['id'] = $id;`

Comment: ya...i removed it from the same!!!

Comment: @KunalTewatia Please add complete index.php and home.php pages in question.

Comment: removing echo will not do make any difference. I want to check your conditions.

Comment: @AmitGupta Done!!!
Please chk it 
I also think there is a issue with if....else conditions

Comment: @KunalTewatia Yeh checking your code. Hide header("Location:Home.php?id=$uid"); code from home.php. I think your condition comes here and page keeps on redirecting.

Comment: And use session_start(); in beginning of index.php as well

Comment: multiple redirection stopped...but giving $id in URL
http://localhost/abc/Home.php?id=$id

Comment: If you are passing $id in session then no need to pass in url

Comment: Also use window.location in place of header at home.php

Comment: @AmitGupta It worked....redirected to Home.php
use object in both index.php & home.php

Thanks for helping out!!!

Comment: @KunalTewatia Great! Happy coding!

Comment: @KunalTewatia Don't forget to give upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add **session_start();** at the beginning of `index.php`

Second re-check below code in home.php that results in redirecting of `home.php` again and again.

```
header("Location:Home.php?id=$uid");
```